# How to instruct IBM Websphere MQ to convert JMS Headers from EBCDIC to ASCII

Tags: jms, weblogic, ibm-mq, mom

I have a Java app on Weblogic 11g using a Message Bridge to talk JMS with Websphere MQ. The MQ server is running on IBM z/OS platform which uses EBCDIC encoding. I need to use the Weblogic message selector feature to filter messages on the bridge. But the JMS Headers are in EBCDIC format. How can I instruct MQ to convert the msg headers to ASCII before put on the bridge?

Answer (score 1):

JMS headers will be in Unicode 1208. No need of any conversion.